# Breaking from Pandas read_csv when condition met while using chunks

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv

I am using Pandas to read in a text file and trim the data using read_csv. I would like to expedite the program by stopping the csv_read when a certain string value is met, but I can't seem to do this while working with chunks. My data follows a regular pattern like so:

```
v 2298995.721525 14888281.709655 4538.717779 0.015686 0.035294 0.019608
v 2298996.930769 14888284.103022 4538.596748 0.023529 0.031373 0.027451
v 2299001.331951 14888295.376948 4538.696330 0.027451 0.043137 0.031373
... (about 4.5 million lines of this)

f 155739//155739 157296//157296 156114//156114
f 157296//157296 160780//160780 156113//156113
f 159990//159990 157296//157296 155739//155739
... (about 10 million lines of this)
```

I can read and output the data, but it would save considerable processing time if I stopped the read_csv when it detected the 'f' string in the first column. Here is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

#assign names to columns
colnames = ['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

#assign chunk size
c_size=200000

#read input file with space separated columns, strip header, and strip extra columns
for obj_chunk in pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1],sep='\s+', header=3, usecols=[0,1,2,3],chunksize=c_size, ):
    dtype={'ID':str,'X':int, 'Y':int, 'Z':int}
    obj_chunk.columns = colnames
    obj_chunk = obj_chunk[~obj_chunk.ID.str.contains('f')]
    obj_chunk.to_csv(sys.argv[2], index=False, header=None, columns = ['X','Y','Z'], mode = 'a')
```

I've tried some "if" then "break" statements, but I don't think I'm on the right track:

```
if obj_chunk[obj_chunk.ID.str.contains('f').any]: break
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I tried your statement and I keep getting KeyErrors: True or False depending on which string expression I use. I might not be placing this in the correct spot? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One idea: if all lines of chunk dataframe are saved, that means we have not a 'f' in first column, either, that means some rows have been suppressed and the number of rows is < size of chunk (or its end of file) so, 
i will test the number of row, inside loop:

```
#assign chunk size
c_size=200000

for obj_chunk in pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1],sep='\s+', header=3, usecols= [0,1,2,3],chunksize=c_size, ):
    dtype={'ID':str,'X':int, 'Y':int, 'Z':int}
    obj_chunk.columns = colnames
    obj_chunk = obj_chunk[~obj_chunk.ID.str.contains('f')]
    obj_chunk.to_csv(sys.argv[2], index=False, header=None, columns = ['X','Y','Z'], mode = 'a')
    #test nbr of lines
    if obj_chunk['ID'].count() < c_size:
        break
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thank you! Your addition reduced my processing time by 24%, so I'd say it was worthwhile!